# Emacs unexpectedly switches buffer to scratch buffer

Tags: emacs, window

Emacs newbie here. I'd like to start an eshell in a split window when opening a makefile. So I added the following to my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 
  'makefile-mode-hook 
  (lambda () 
    (progn 
      (split-window-right 110)
      (other-window 1)
      (eshell)
      (other-window 1))))
```

I get the eshell as planned, however, my original buffer switches from the makefile to the scratch buffer, for reasons unknown. Why is this?

Also, if I leave out the `eshell` invocation and the last "other-window", I still get the scratch buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `makefile-mode-hook` runs before the actual file is opened in a window, and the window-switching screws up with switching the original window to the newly-opened buffer.

So you can work around this by doing the window-shuffling after everything has settled, in an idle callback:

```
(add-hook 
 'makefile-mode-hook 
 (lambda ()
   (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil
     (lambda () 
       (split-window-right 110)
       (other-window 1)
       (eshell)
       (other-window -1)))))
```

**Update**: I didn't like this whole stateful "select next window" / "select previous window" nonsense, and thought there has to be a better way. And turns out there is! `save-selected-window` allows for an excursion-style temporary window change, and `with-selected-window`, built on top of that, allows for a temporary window change into a new window:

```
(add-hook
 'makefile-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil
     (lambda ()
       (with-selected-window (split-window-right 110)
         (eshell))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I've just cooked up:

```
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
          'makefile-open-eshell)

(defvar makefile-eshell-in-progress nil)

(defun makefile-open-eshell ()
  (interactive)
  (unless makefile-eshell-in-progress
    (when (memq major-mode
                '(makefile-mode makefile-gmake-mode))
      (let ((dir (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
            (window (cl-find-if
                     (lambda (window)
                       (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
                         (eq major-mode 'eshell-mode)))
                     (window-list))))
        (if window
            (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
              (unless (file-equal-p dir (eshell/pwd))
                (eshell/cd dir)
                (eshell-send-input)))
          (let ((makefile-eshell-in-progress t))
            ;; (delete-other-windows)
            (split-window-right)
            (other-window 1)
            (eshell)
            (eshell/cd dir)
            (eshell-send-input)
            (other-window -1)))))))
```

This should always open an appropriate eshell when you switch to a
Makefile.

Use this to stop the madness:

```
(remove-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
             'makefile-open-eshell)
```

Comment: This works on startup, but splits the eshell window when I exit from the eshell or try to kill its buffer (an undesirable behavior), and more importantly I still have no idea why this works or why my original version doesn't.

Comment: You're not supposed to kill eshell before Makefile for this code.
Anyway, the answer for your question is: `(other-window -1)`, probably.

Comment: `other-window -1` doesn't help. To clarify things, I'd just like to be able to open a file and have eshell in a split window, I don't need anything fancier than that.